# How to stop the spinner after the loading finishes in an angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, progress-bar, dc.js

I am implementing a spinner which is working fine initially, but it continues to spin even after the page has been loaded.

### loader.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {
    public status: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    display(value: boolean) {
        this.status.next(value);
    }
}
```

### app.module.ts

imported the LoadService and added it to the providers array

### app.component.html

I am checking the value of showLoader to see if it is true or false as true would show the loader and false wouldn't.

```
<router-outlet>
   <span *ngIf="showLoader" class="loading"></span>{{showLoader}}
</router-outlet>
```

### app.component.ts

imported LoaderService

```
export class AppComponent {
  //for the spinner
  showLoader: boolean;
  //LoaderService is for the spinner
  constructorprivate loaderService: LoaderService) { }
  //for the spinner
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService.status.subscribe((val: boolean) => {
      this.showLoader = val;
    });
  }
}
```

### custom.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom',
  templateUrl: './custom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom.component.css']
})
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

    //LoaderService is for the spinner
    constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        //http call starts
        this.loaderService.display(true);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        d3.json("https://...", function(data) {
            createChart(data);
        });
        function createChart(data) {
            ...

            dc.renderAll();
        }//end of function  
    }//end of ngAfterView
}//end of export class
```

I am showing some dc charts and I want the spinner to stop once the charts are displayed.

I need to stop the spinner with `this.loaderService.display(false);` but using it right after dc.renderAll(); is showing the value of showLoader as false and thereby no spinner appears.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add a default value for `showLoader` in your AppComponent.
You can set it to `true` as a default with `showLoader: boolean = true;`

```
export class AppComponent {
  //for the spinner
  showLoader: boolean = true;
  //LoaderService is for the spinner
  constructorprivate loaderService: LoaderService) { }
  //for the spinner
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService.status.subscribe((val: boolean) => {
      this.showLoader = val;
    });
  }
}
```

The spinner will be shown by default.
Then you can set it like this.

**custom.component.ts**

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let loaderService = this.loaderService;
    d3.json("https://...", function(data) {
        createChart(data);
    });
    function createChart(data) {
        ...

        dc.renderAll();
        loaderService.display(false);
    }//end of function  
  }//end of ngAfterView
```

Comment: can you please elaborate? I didn't quite understand what you said.

Comment: Replace `showLoader: boolean;`with `showLoader: boolean = true;`

Comment: and where would `this.loaderService.display(false);` be in the custom.component.ts?

Comment: Exactly. It's turned on by default and the hidden when what you want to show is loaded.

Comment: Where would `this.loaderService.display(false);` be in custom.component.ts?

Comment: I edited my answer with what you should add in custom.component.ts

Comment: I am getting the error cannot find name loaderService

Comment: Did you add this at the top of  ngAfterViewInit ? `let loaderService = this.loaderService;`

Comment: Ah I had missed that! Thank you for pointing that out. It now works. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If understood you correctly, dc.renderAll() is an async function, therefore you'll need to restructure your app so that you hide the spinner **AFTER** the function has actually ended processing.

One way to do this is by turning the renderAll() into an observable and subscribing to it, calling loaderService.display(false) inside the subscription.

```
dc.renderAll().subscribe(
  value => this.loaderService.display(false)
)
```

Comment: I am getting the error cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined.

Comment: You should refactor your renderAll function so that it returns an Observable.